# How to fix TChart Axis Margin Delphi

Tags: delphi, teechart

I was a dynamic data, and I want to show it on the same TChart. How can I fix the axis margin with different data?

For Example:

First Data Have a 'thousand' value

[image]

Second Data Have a 'hundred' value

[image]

I want my TChart have same margin for any value. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried the solution discussed [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10620)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can set it by forcing the label width to a given value.

```
TChart1.Axis.Left.Labels.Size := 30;
```

So that it always stay at the same width.

With the interface it's here

[image]

Comment: In Delphi 10.3, it should be Chart1.LeftAxis.LabelsSize:=30;